# Why does my skybox light rotate when my character rotates?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have an issue where my skybox lighting in the scene and game windows rotates when my character rotates.  The game has a top down view and is running in the HDRP render pipeline (Unity version: 2021.3.4f1). I'm currently using a procedural sky. There are no additional lights added to the scene and the camera does not rotate, it just follows the player keeping the player in the center of the screen.  At one point it was working fine and the skybox lighting was only ever facing one direction. However, while working on unrelated gameplay mechanics the skybox lighting has now permanently started to rotate with the player character.  Why is this occurring and how can I fix this?

Comment: probably your skybox is children of the character in your scene hierarchy. Parent and children move along together as if they were the same object :)

Comment: Thanks so much @rustyBucketBay this was the case.  I must have dragged the directional light into the character accidentally when moving things around in the scene.